# SAS phreg. How to divide the dataset for separatly analysis?

Tags: sas

SAS dataset includes data from two centers (= 1 and 2). How to make phreg for each center separately?

```
proc phreg data = a;
INPUT center time censor gender;
class gender;
model time*censor(0) = gender; 
run;
```

Comment: Can you have an INPUT in proc PHREG? I'm not sure that makes sense or will work the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you for attention, Reeza! You're right! It's not need!

Answer (score 1):

```
proc sort data = a;
 by center;
run;
proc phreg data = a; 
 input time censor gender;
 class gender;
 model time*censor(0) = gender;
 by center;
run;
```

is one way.  Another is

```
proc phreg data = a; 
 input time censor gender;
 class gender;
 model time*censor(0) = gender;
 where center = 1;
run;
```

and then do it again with center = 2

Comment: What would the INPUT statement do in Proc Phreg?

Comment: Thanks, Reeza! No need!